# SQL - Extracting first 5 consecutive numbers from alphanumeric string

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, alphanumeric

I am using AWS Athena, so functions are a bit limiting. But essentially I want to extract the first 5 consecutive and sequential numbers from a alphanumeric field.

[image]

From the first example, you can see it ignores the first 1 because there aren't 4 trailing numbers. I want to find and extract the first 5 numbers that are given together from this field. The output field is what I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: add the expected result for more clarity on the ask

Comment: @MoulitharanM - it's already there (the Output column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find an exact sequence of 5 digits.
a sequence of less or more than 5 digits will be ignored.

```
^|\D  = Indication for the start of the text OR a non-digit character
\d{5} = 5 digits
\D|$  = A non-digit character OR indication for the end of the text
```

---

```
with t (Example) as (values ('Ex/l/10345/Pl'), ('Ex/23453PlWL'), ('ID09456//'))
select Example, regexp_extract(Example, '(^|\D)(\d{5})(\D|$)', 2) as Output
from   t
```

---

```
+---------------+--------+
|    Example    | Output |
+---------------+--------+
| Ex/l/10345/Pl |  10345 |
| Ex/23453PlWL  |  23453 |
| ID09456//     |  09456 |
+---------------+--------+
```